# How to load all resources from silverlight assembly?

Tags: xml, file, load

I have a silverlight assembly which has several xml files. All these files are embedded as resources. I don't know the file names as well. I need to load all files and construct in memory dictionary with the data.
I know how to load xml file if i know the file names. as shown below

```
this.filePath = string.Format(@"/{0};component/internal/{1}", assemblyName, "TaxRules.xml");
StreamResourceInfo streamResourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(filePath, UriKind.Relative));
        Stream stream = streamResourceInfo.Stream;
        //check for performance
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
```

I don't know to how load all xml files without knowing file names..
any help on this is highly appreacited

Answer (score 0):

If the build action on the XML file is an Embedded Resource and you are in the Assembly you can you get it from the assembly

e.g.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

var names = (from n in asm.GetManifestResourceNames()
                         where n.EndsWith(".xml")
                         select n
                         ).ToList();
```

then when you want the stream you use `GetManifestResourceStream`

e.g.

```
   Dictionary<string, System.IO.Stream> resources = new Dictionary<string,System.IO.Stream>();
   foreach (string name in names)
   {
          resources.Add(name, asm.GetManifestResourceStream(name));

   }
```

note: tested with VS 2010 SilverLight Toolkit 4

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your help. How about if it a just resource? what is the difference between resource and embedded resource? the xml files are not part of the same assmebly..

Comment: An embedded resource  exists within the assembly. (this is what I though you meant with "embedded as resources") A resource if I understand it correctly follows the [Pack URI Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx). I don't know how to enumerate those resources. Sorry